# Google analytics shows "data receiving" but cannot see any data on the analytics page

Tags: google-analytics

In my google analytics screen, the status shows "Data Receiving", but I cannot see any report. It has been almost 2 months since I had revamped my website & after that I am getting this issue. Previously I was using ga.js. I changed the code to use analytics.js without changing any settings in the analytics account will this be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

For using analytics.js, you should create a new web property which will give a new tracking ID and use it in your website. You should not be reusing the old property which you were using with ga.js. Best way to test this by retaining the earlier ga.js tracking code and additionally adding the analytics.js tracking code based on the new property. G[oogle also recommends](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/) this approach for migrating from ga.js to analytics.js

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you think there is any way to view the data that has been recorded using analytics.js code. Because that is quite important for the client.

Comment: if google analytics was not able to record your site views during a certain period, you will not be able to get it. are you seeing any hits in realtime report while you are browsing the site with your current setup? after checking this can you confirm if by reverting back to ga.js code and adding additional analytic.js code based on a new web property, are you able to get data in google analytics for both the properties?

Comment: ok will try, but the problem is the client dosent give me any access to their GA. I will check with them if they can try doing this for me.